# Recurrence relations and Generating functions - how to find the initial conditions?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Best to ask by example. Given the recurrence relation $a_{n}=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$, and some given initial conditions, we can find a similar relation for the generating function for the sequence, $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$: 
$$f(x)=xf(x)+x^2f(x)+c(x)$$
Where $c(x)$ is a polynomial encoding the initial conditions. My main question is how can this polynomial be computed as painlessly as possible from the initial conditions? This is interesting not only for Fibonacci but in general, of course.

A similar, probably equivalent questions is this: If for some sequence we have a rational generating function $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ then the coefficients of $q(x)$ are exactly the coefficients of the recurrence relation for the sequence. Also, $p(x)$ is dependent on the initial conditions - but again, it's not clear to me how to compute those initial conditions from $p(x)$.

Comment: I added the $x^n$ that you left out of the generating function.

Comment: We know $f(0)$ and $f'(0)$. That's enough to determine $c(x)$.

Comment: André, I'm not sure I understand. Would you like to elaborate in an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your initial conditions are $a_0$ and $a_1$, $p(x)=c(x)=(a_1-a_0)x+a_0$. Look at it this way. You have $$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}\tag{1}$$ for $n\ge 2$. Assume that $a_n=0$ for $n<0$. Then $(1)$ is valid for *all* integers $n$ except possibly $0$ and $1$. To make it valid for all integers, add a couple of terms using the [Iverson bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) to get $$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+(a_1-a_0)[n=1]+a_0[n=0]\;.\tag{2}$$

Note that while $a_0$ is straightforward, you have to be careful for $n>0$, since the earlier initial values are automatically built into the basic recurrence.

Now multiply $(2)$ through by $x^n$ and sum:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_na_nx^n&=\sum_na_{n-1}x^n+\sum_na_{n-2}x^n+(a_1-a_0)\sum_n[n=1]x^n+a_0\sum_n[n=0]x^n\\
&=x\sum_na_nx^n+x^2\sum_na_nx^n+(a_1-a_0)x+a_0\;.
\end{align*}$$

Thus, if your generating function is $A(x)=\displaystyle\sum_na_nx^n$, you have $$A(x)=xA(x)+x^2A(x)+(a_1-a_0)x+a_0\;,$$ and hence $$A(x)=\frac{(a_1-a_0)x+a_0}{1-x-x^2}\;.$$

This obviously generalizes to higher-order recurrences and other starting points for the initial values. For example, a third-order recurrence with initial values $a_0,a_1,a_2$ would have

$$\begin{align*}
p(x)=c(x)&=a_0+(a_1-a_0)x+\left(a_2-\big(a_0+(a_1-a_0)\big)\right)x^2\\
&=a_0+(a_1-a_0)x+(a_2-a_1)x^2\;.
\end{align*}$$

In general with initial values $a_0,\dots,a_m$ you’ll get Iverson terms

$$a_0[n=0]+(a_1-a_0)[n=1]+(a_2-a_1)[n=2]+\cdots+(a_m-a_{m-1})[n=m]$$

in the recurrence and

$$c(x)=p(x)=a_0+(a_1-a_0)x+\cdots+(a_m-a_{m-1})x^m\;.$$

Comment: Your $c(x)$ is incorrect because (2) does not hold for $n=1$. As a consequence, the ratio $(a_1x+a_0)/(1-x-x^2)$ is $a_0+(a_1+a_0)x+$higher terms and not $a_0+a_1x+$higher terms.

Comment: As pointed out, this naive c(x) is tempting but incorrect. I had the same mistake myself, and this is the reason I'm asking the question.

Comment: For example (copied my from Sage):
sage: f(x) = (x+1)/(1-x-x^2)                
sage: f.taylor('x', 0, 5)                   
x |--> 13*x^5 + 8*x^4 + 5*x^3 + 3*x^2 + 2*x + 1

Comment: @Didier: Fixed. Not the first time I’ve done that; you’d think that I’d know better by now. (I’ve worked too many classroom examples with $a_0=0$, I think!)

Answer (score 3):

Look at a slightly more general problem $a_n=pa_{n-1}+qa_{n-2}$. As in your Fibonacci case, we get
$$f(x)=pxf(x)+qx^2f(x)+c(x).$$
Since $f(0)=a_0$, we have $c(0)=a_0$.
Now differentiate, and note that $a_1=f'(0)$. (In general, $a_n n!=f^{(n)}(0)$.)

We get 
$$f'(x)=pxf'(x)+pf(x)+qx^2f'(x)+2qxf(x)+c'(x),$$
so 
$$c'(0)=f'(0)-pf(0)=a_1-pa_0.$$
Since everything is determined once $a_0$ and $a_1$ are known, $c(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $\le 1$, and therefore $c(x)=c'(0)x+c(0)=(a_1-pa_0)x+a_0$.

Repeated differentiation also has to work for your more general question, since the derivatives at $0$ determine the coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

If you have:
$$
A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n
$$
then also:
$$
\frac{A(z)}{1 - z} = \sum_{n \ge 0} \left(\sum_{0 \le k \le n} a_k \right) z^n
$$
(multiply out, the inner sums telescope away leaving just the last terms).

Answer (score 1):

General technique is to write your recurrence so there are no subtractions in indices:

$$
a_{n + 2} = a_{n + 1} + a_n
$$

Multiply by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$:

$$
\sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 2} z^n
  = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 1} z^n
      + \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n
$$

Recogize some sums:

$$
\frac{A(z) - a_0 - a_1 z}{z^2}
  = \frac{A(z) - a_0}{z}
       + A(z)
$$

If you solve this for $A(z)$, you get a rational function in $z$. The numerator encodes the initial values, the denominator depends only on the recurrence.